# Integrating jQuery DatePicker Calendar into Page

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I am trying to integrate the jQuery datepicker calendar into my page. I don't want the user to have to click on the date field for the calendar to appear, I want them to be able to see the calendar as soon as the page loads. Is this doable, and if so, how?

I have been looking on StackOverflow for help but I'm not sure whether what I'm searching for is the correct way of describing it.

Thanks very much.

Comment: Which datepicker plugin do you want to use? The "official" jquery UI datepicker?

Comment: Yep, that's the one I was looking at. :) If there are others that are easier though I'd probably look at those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in the [documentation at jqueryui.com](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#inline), you might simply call the `.datepicker()` method on a div instead of an input field to display the datepicker inline.

The only problem arousing of this usecase is the fasct, that you won't get the date directly inserted in an input field.  You can retrieve the value by calling `$("#yourDatepickerDiv").datepicker( 'getDate' );`

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand what you are asking.  You basically would just have to give the input focus on page load.  I made a small [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vreoq7zs/) to show this.  Essentially it would just be

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.date').datepicker().focus();
});
```

Comment: This would show the datepicker on startup but hide it as soon as the user clicks on anything else.

Comment: That is true, reading the question, the only requirement @Fran specified was that the datepicker be open on page load.

Comment: You are absolutely right! My comment should just help future readers to understand the differences between those two solutions.